# Log4j2 JSP Taglib not working in Spring-boot Embedded Servlet Containers

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have a Spring boot web application which I created using the [spring-boot-starter-web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web) artifact. I am using Spring Boot Embedded Servlet Containers features to use the Tomcat embedded server. I am able to run my app in Tomcat embedded mode. I can also create a WAR file of my app and deploy it to a normal installation of Tomcat.

I have one JSP page in which I am using [log4j2's JSP taglib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-taglib) tags. On a normal installation of Tomcat the logging from that JSP page works as expected. But when bootRun on the Tomcat embedded server I get the following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [The absolute uri: [http://logging.apache.org/log4j/tld/log] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://logging.apache.org/log4j/tld/log] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Can this issue be solved?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what the problem is. Can you share a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Andy, I did create a small example project at https://github.com/rahulkhimasia/SpringBootLog4j2Taglib.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because Spring Boot skips `log4j-*.jar` by default. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23302) to address this.

You can work around the problem by explicitly enabling scanning of the `log4j-taglib` jar. To do so, you need to add a `TomcatContextCustomizer` that changes the configuration of the jar scanner:

```java
@Bean
TomcatContextCustomizer log4jTldScanningCustomizer() {
    return (context) -> 
        ((StandardJarScanFilter)context.getJarScanner().getJarScanFilter()).setTldScan("log4j-taglib*.jar");
}
```